# AngularRest API wont return JSON property

Tags: angularjs, json, rest, asp.net-web-api

I have 3 components, the web api, the controller, and the html. I can hit the web api just fine and i get back the results in JSON format, but when it then tries to render the JSON into the html, it looks like this.

```
{
    "Projects": [{
        "ProjectId": 1,
        "Name": "Project1",
        "Key": "Software",
        "ProjectTypeKey": "1"
    }, {
        "ProjectId": 2,
        "Name": "Project2",
        "Key": "Hardware",
        "ProjectTypeKey": "2"
    }, {
        "ProjectId": 3,
        "Name": "Project3",
        "Key": "Hardware",
        "ProjectTypeKey": "3"
    }]
}
```

WebApi

```
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        listProjects.Add(new Project { ProjectId = 1, Name = "Project1", Key = "Software", ProjectTypeKey = "1" });
        listProjects.Add(new Project { ProjectId = 2, Name = "Project2", Key = "Hardware", ProjectTypeKey = "2" });

        listEmployeeProject.Add(new EmployeeProject {Projects = listProjects });

        return Json(listEmployeeProject);
    }
```

Controller

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.service('dataService', function ($http) {

this.getData = function () {
    // $http() returns a $promise that we can add handlers with .then()
    return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/api/employee'           
    });
}
});

myApp.controller('ProjectController', function ($scope, dataService) {
$scope.Projects = [];
dataService.getData().then(function (result) {
    $scope.Projects = result.data;
});
});
```

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ProjectController">
{{1 + 1}}

<div ng-repeat="project in Projects">
    {{project}}
</div>
```

Even when i switch {{project}} to {{project.Name}}, nothing renders on the page.

console.log(results.data) looks like below

[image]

Comment: `{{1 + 1}}` is rendered?

Comment: yes this renders as 2

Comment: Have to checked what you're getting in `result.data`?

Comment: Any errors on `console`? Put a `console.log(result.data)` in your `then` `function`.

Comment: results.data is an array of 3 objects

Comment: console logged the array of the 3 objects, no errors on console

Comment: @Monzingo, have you tested `$scope.Projects = result.data.Projects;`?

Comment: result.data.Projects; did not return anything for project.Name

Comment: It works for me.. [**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/sakAmWDKd1nrCNIaB7k5?p=preview)

Comment: but i would like to only display the Name, so wouldnt it be project.Name?

Comment: Yes.. it should be `project.Name`.

Comment: So, does it works?

Comment: it looks like your `result.data` is an object with a property `Projects` that is the actual array.  try `$scope.Projects = result.data.Projects;`.

Comment: result.data.Projects returns nothing.

Comment: The issue was within my model. I had a Class that was a list of a class and this was throwing off the JSON result. Not sure how it would be possible to achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its very clear from your console that you are returning an array of length 1 which has another array of length 3 in it

This is because of this line in your code

```
listEmployeeProject.Add(new EmployeeProject {Projects = listProjects });
```

Here you are retuning a EmployeeProject array and each element of that array has multiple projects. So do either of these things

a. Return `listProjects` like return `Json(listProjects)` (You should be returning `Ok(model)` ideally)

b. Or in angular promise do,

```
$scope.Projects = result.data[0].Projects;
```